# Package installer crashes while getting runtime permission in Marshmallow

Tags: java, android

In my application am getting runtime permission from user. My problem is when getting permission from user am getting "Unfortunately package installer has stopped".
Here is my **Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="place.picker.mymarket">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_market_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".LaunchActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".IntroductionSlider"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".oneTimeValidation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".list_my_posts"
        android:label="deletion list"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Upload_to_server"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SharePost"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_login" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_place_api" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Nopost"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".FeedbackActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AboutUs"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".FAQ"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".PostDesign"></activity>
</application>
```

Here is my permissions string array in java

```
arr = new String[] {
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE};
```

Here is how am checking permission

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        int k=0;
        for(String p:arr){
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(IntroductionSlider.this,p)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                perms[k++]=p;
            }
        }
        if(perms.length==0) {
            startActivity(new Intent(IntroductionSlider.this, oneTimeValidation.class));
            finish();

        }else {
            requestPerm(perms);
        }


    }
```

Here is my requestPerm() method

```
    private void requestPerm(String[] permis) {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(IntroductionSlider.this,permis,ALL_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

This is what i did,but do no what is the issue can anyone help me please am new to android.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add an exception log...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I forgot to add same permissions in manifest. I added these permissions in manifest as well as mike said. Then it works.

If you are giving the permissions programmatically in class then make sure the same permissions you must declare in AndroidManifest.xml file.